# How to organize e2e tests for Spring app with RDS as a storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, end-to-end

We have a Spring Boot application, which uses RDS service for storing data (PostgreSQL, VPC + private subnet particularly) and Cognito for the user authentication. All this jazz is deployed in automation (Jenkins + CloudFormation). Now, we have a few end2end tests, checking that app is alive. The question is, should we go further and try to test the functionality, requiring some test user to be authorized. Personally, I would prefer it to be tested, but there are some obstacles which I don't know how to approach.

- Normally within e2e testing, you would like to have a clear DB at the beginning of each test (or a bunch of tests) with similar preconditions. For that, you apply a snapshot with the desired state of DB or simply drop all tables.

  Is it possible to do it on the AWS (DB is not publicly accessible)? Am I supposed to use [RestoreDBInstanceFromDBSnapshot command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_RestoreDBInstanceFromDBSnapshot.html) for that or there are other ways to do this? How to prevent case when DB schema has changed, but we still restore from the old snapshot?
- We can have special endpoints just for the test environment, but it is kind of unfavored because it messes up the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Not sure how you get your release out like application and database patch at the same time or different releases depending upon if there is a database change. As a lot will depend on this
- I prefer the e2e test cleanup the database data after them. What i mean is this test insert data into database and may be in the teardown method or may be a totally new test deletes all the record created by/for testing and in between this 2 process you can carryout your normal tests.
- Here i am assuming that you are following the test pyramid with e2e test being the slowest and less in quantity compared to system integration and unit test.
- This might be a bit tricky depending on the scenarios you want to test and when running simultaneous/concurrent tests, there is a workaround here to use different data for each test.
- I would prefer you apply a snapshot with the desired state(here i mean not with the pre-populated testing data, but just the table schema with required master data).
- If there is a schema change you would still take a backup of the existing, apply the new script changes for schema and then run the test.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Have you applied snapshots on RDS? How have you done this?

Comment: @quietbird I would prefer using restore-db-instance-to-point-in-time. Hope this is helpful https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/implementing-a-disaster-recovery-strategy-with-amazon-rds/ and the actual https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PIT.html